# How can I display buttons on a js alert

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a message being showed by a button like this:

```
 string script = "alert(\"Cadastro realizado com sucesso. Deseja continuar cadastrando?\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

I would like to know if is it possible to add to buttons and then make actions. is it?

This is in C# and webforms

Comment: It's not possible on an `alert()`, no.  There is a `prompt()` which has an input and a button, but that's not very flexible either.  For custom functionality what you're probably looking for is to create something like a modal `div` to simulate a "popup".

Comment: great! can you suggest any contents? I've been searching like crazy but no clue where to go

Comment: It's a bit more involved than a single line of code to replace the line of code you have.  At its simplest you basically want to create a part of the page that's styled to be hidden by default, place your content within that part, and dynamically show/hide that content based on your logic.  (This is generally better done client-side than server-side, but that's up to you.)  There exist JavaScript plugins to help with this, such as Bootstrap modals or jQuery UI dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: swal and handle in jquery

```
swal({
        title: "",
        text: message,
        type: type,
        confirmButtonText: ''
    }
```